# Why doesn’t stopping an application in iOS simulator trigger applicationWillTerminate:?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios-simulator

I have some code in my `AppDelegate`’s `applicationWillTerminate:` method but I don’t know how to test if it works. Using Xcode to stop the simulator does not trigger it.

How do I test the code in applicationWillTerminate:?

Please note that this is specific to the simulator and not the device.

Comment: Maybe kill it. Since iOS 4, apps don't terminate upon being quit, they are just suspended.

Comment: The code in that method should probably be in `applicationDidEnterBackground:` - what does it do?

Comment: It synchronises the NSUserDefaults. I have put it in `applicationDidEnterBackground:` too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [applicationWillTerminate not getting called on force quit of iOS app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13386505/applicationwillterminate-not-getting-called-on-force-quit-of-ios-app)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The simulator doesn't send `applicationWillTerminate:` because the springboard isn't sending you the kill code (SIGABRT), LLDB is.  To trigger those delegate methods, you have to use the Home Button command (⌘+⇧+H), then pull up the multitasking drawer and kill your application from there.  Your debugging session will immediately terminate, and the delegate method will fire successfully.

Comment: sadly not doing the business in iOS 9.1

Answer (score 2):

The only way it worked with me was after I did the following steps:

1. Edit the target schema
2. Select `Run` tap
3. Choose `Wait for the execution to be launched` as a launch option
4. Run the app from Xcode
5. Open the app on the simulator/device
6. double click the home button
7. remove the app from background

[image: Wait for the execution to be launched]

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 9.1 (perhaps before) this only seems to work if you double click home and drag the app up so it exits.  Doing it from the desktop doesn't fire this event, it has to happen while the app is open in the simulator.

[image]

Comment: This did it for me, although it is way harder to double tap home on the Simulator than it should be. 90% of the Simulator would background the app. It's much easier to just ⇧⌘H twice in a row.